# dynamically enabling dates of the datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Kindly help me to modify below prog so as to accept user input and enable/disable day of the datepicker.
Example: currently Saturday and sunday are enabled. I would like to modify this prog to read numbers(0  to 6) from the user and enabling the dates.

http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/q9dEB/

```
<input type='text' id='txtDate' />

$(function () {
    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (dt) {
            return [dt.getDay() == 1 || dt.getDay() == 2, ""];
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you So much...I could able to resolve this ..

User has to enter valid number for Start day(low as 0) and End day( high as 6)

Here You go

http://jsfiddle.net/shrikanth/q9dEB/139/

```
      <p><b>Sun-0 Mon-1 Tue-2 Wed-3 Thu-4 Fri-5 Sat-6</b></p><br />
      Enter No :<input type='text' id='a' /><br />
     Enter No :<input type='text' id='b'   /><br />
     Calender : <input type='text' id='txtDate'/>


      $(function(){    
      $("#txtDate").click(function (){


     $('#txtDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay:
     function(dt)
     {var i= $("#a").val();
       var j= $("#b").val();

    return [dt.getDay() >= i && dt.getDay() <= j, ""];
  }
  });
  });
 });
```

Comment: Ok.. well, You shouldn't post answers like comments; and if your answer was the correct answer - you should mark it as the correct answer (The tick)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#txtDate').datepicker({ 
    beforeShowDay: function( dt ) {
        //Between Monday to Saturday
        return [dt.getDay() >= 1 && dt.getDay() <= 6, ""];
    }
});
```

If I'm correct in thinking you're wishing to *exclude* Sundays, the above will match against Monday to Saturday.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/UdGZX/